How do high temperature superconductors behave at low temperatures (order of $\rm mK$)?
How do high temperature superconductors having $T_c \sim 90$K behave at low temperature (order of $\rm mK$)? Will it become paramagnetic? How does the interaction happen at low temperatures (range of $\rm mK$) and at higher temperatures (around critical temperatures)?

Superconductivity is a phase transition; generally people mean, if they do not state otherwise, that at any temperature below $T_c$, it is superconducting. Which means it is not paramagnetic. I mean, after you freeze water into ice below the melting point, do you expect the ice to suddenly be liquid or gaseous at milli-Kelvins? There can be other solid phases, but we would tend to state them if you need to consider them.

Essentially superconductivity becomes more robust at lower temperatures. More robust means larger gap, higher critical current, higher critical magnetic field. In other words, it is easy to destroy superconductivity when you are close to Tc but it costs more energy when you are at low temperatures. For BCS superconductors, applications aim to work at temperatures at or below Tc/2 where most properties are close to their 0K value. Unless a superconductor has particular phase transitions (look for reentrant superconductivity, for ex.) being close to 0K does not change a lot its properties.
